# Why *p returning an integer for (char*p = "hello world")

Tags: c, pointers

Why *pointer is an integer but not the string content "Hello from pointer" Thanks!

```
int main(void) {
  char *pointer;
  pointer = "Hello from pointer";

  printf("*pointer is %d\n", *pointer);
  printf("\n");
}
```

the output is *pointer is 72

Comment: `*p` is 72 as `'H'` is 72 - first character in `"Hello from pointer"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because the ASCII code for `'H'` (which is the first element of the array) is `72`. It is completely normal.

[Here is the ASCII Code table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUrxp.png)

Answer (score 3):

`pointer = "Hello from pointer";` is pointing to the first letter of this string literal which is `H` and **ASCII** Value of `'H'` is 72, that's why the output is 72.

In C, a `constant character string` always represents a pointer to that string. And therefore this statement is valid:

`char *pointer = "Hello...";`

This statement declares `pointer` as a `pointer to character` and assigns to `pointer` the constant character string `"Hello..."`

That'ss why when you `printf("%d", *pointer);` it outputs `72`. Because, `pointer` is pointing to the **first character** of that constant string literal, which is `'H'` and because of the format flag `%d` in `printf()` statement, it prints out the **ASCII** value of `'H'`, which is 72. Hope you got your explanation.

Comment: well it is pointing to the string literal, thats exactly what it is doing

Comment: no it contains the address of the character 'H', thats why *pointer prints 72

Comment: A string literal produces an array of `char`, and `p` points to the first of those.

Comment: indeed , so that pointer contains the address of the literal in memory

Answer (score 2):

Here `printf("*pointer is %d\n", *pointer);` in this line you've used **%d** format specifier, not **%s** to print out the string pointer.
Again you should not de-reference the pointer variable when you print string from the string pointer. Try to search and find about **String array vs String pointer**.
So, the line should be `printf("*pointer is %s\n", pointer);`

**More explanation:**
`char *pointer = "Hello from pointer";`
After compiling this line, "Hello from pointer" will be stored in the memory. And like array variable, the pointer variable will hold the base address of this character array. So, the variable **pointer** will hold the address of **H** here.

Thus when you de-reference the pointer variable, it will show the value **H**. As the format specifier you used is **%d**, it's printing the integer value (ASCII Value) of the character **H** (72).

Answer (score -1):

This is caused by a buffer overflow. (Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow))

The direct answer is because 72 is the integer representation of the character "H" from "Hello from pointer".

Basically, there's two things going on.

1) That variable only expects you to give it one `char`

2) A pointer only points to a single part in memory, so since strings are treated sort of like "arrays" (per se), you're getting only the first value in the "array"

So if you were to print `*pointer[1]` you would get `e`. So the idea is to know the length of your string so you can safely determine how much space you need.

But remember, memory is volatile, so even though whatever compiler you use will open up a certain amount of "stack memory", you can overflow that with a long string.

If you don't know the length of your string and/or your string is very long, you can dynamically allocate it with `malloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: Oh, but if you define `pointer` as `char*[] pointer` it would work, correct?